# Best way to union on spatial condition in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Given an RDD of points represented as tuples of tuples `<x,y>`, I want to map them to a PairRDD of points the form `<<point1>, <point2>>` where `point1` and `point2` respect a certain predicate.

Currently, I attempt this by first creating the cartesian product of the points RDD and then filtering based on the predicate. In Java, this look as follows:

```java
JavaRDD points = getPoints();
JavaPairRdd pointPairs = points.cartesian(points)
          .filter((Function<Tuple2<Tuple2, Tuple2>, Boolean>) t -> {
            return predicate(t._1(), t._2());
        });
```

Where predicate is a function that checks if the second argument is within a certain distance from the first.

```java
boolean predicate(Tuple2<Float,Float> center, Tuple2<Float,Float> point){
      float offset = getOffset(); // this functions as a constant, can be ignored
      // Check if the x and y coordinate of the point lie close to the center
     return Math.abs(point._1() - center._1() <= offset) && Math.abs(point._2() - center._2() <= offset)
}
```

However, this approach is extremely slow, even for a small dataset. Since the cartesian operation is so expensive, I wonder if there is a better way to achieve the same result.

**Update**: the predicate is relatively simple, it checks if `y` is in a certain range from `x`. The dataset contains around a few million points so any O(n^2) operation is not manageable.

For example, assuming we have a point `(56, 12)` in the dataset. The goal is to map this point to all pairs `<(56, 12), (56±offset, 12±offset)>`

Comment: You should try to recode the predicate as a column expression, otherwise Spark has no chance to optimze any execution plans and the cartesian product stays. If the logic for the predicate is too complex for a column expression, you should at least try to transform parts of it, so that the amount of data during the join is reduced. In a second step you can filter the results further with the more complex parts of the predicate

Comment: Can you give some example data for the predicate?

Comment: @werner Thank you for the initial suggestion! I still find it a bit difficult to express the predicate in terms of column expressions but I added more information which I hope makes the intent more clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a data class

```java
public static class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    //getters, setters and constructors
}
```

switching to dataframes might be an option:

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
[...]
List<Point> list = Arrays.asList(new Point(1.0, 1.0), new Point(1.0, 2.0),
        new Point(2.0, 2.0), new Point(10.0, 10.0), new Point(11.0, 11.0));
Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(list, Point.class);

double offset = 2.0;
Column condition = abs(col("x").minus(col("x1"))).leq(offset)
    .and(abs(col("y").minus(col("y1"))).leq(offset));

df = df.join(df.withColumnRenamed("x", "x1").withColumnRenamed("y", "y1"), condition)
    .withColumn("point1", struct("x1", "y1"))
    .groupBy("x", "y")
    .agg(collect_list("point1").as("within_offset"));

df.show(false);
```

prints

```
+----+----+------------------------------------+
|x   |y   |within_offset                       |
+----+----+------------------------------------+
|1.0 |1.0 |[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0]]|
|10.0|10.0|[[10.0, 10.0], [11.0, 11.0]]        |
|2.0 |2.0 |[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0]]|
|1.0 |2.0 |[[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0]]|
|11.0|11.0|[[10.0, 10.0], [11.0, 11.0]]        |
+----+----+------------------------------------+
```

However, the execution plan still contains a cartesian product:

```
== Physical Plan ==
ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[x#0, y#1], functions=[collect_list(point1#22, 0, 0)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(x#0, y#1, 200), true, [id=#71]
   +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(x#0)) AS x#0, knownfloatingpointnormalized(normalizenanandzero(y#1)) AS y#1], functions=[partial_collect_list(point1#22, 0, 0)])
      +- *(1) Project [x#0, y#1, struct(x1, x1#4, y1, y1#7) AS point1#22]
         +- CartesianProduct ((abs((x#0 - x1#4)) <= 2.0) AND (abs((y#1 - y1#7)) <= 2.0))
            :- LocalTableScan [x#0, y#1]
            +- LocalTableScan [x1#4, y1#7]
```